# Boostrap? Am I going insane?

Tags: discussion, spelling

I know some typos are more common than others, but by now "Boostrap" is so incredibly common that I'm beginning to feel it's not them, it's me!

So, the question must be asked. Assuming that "Boostrap" is not the name of some software I'm unaware of (I concluded this by the fact there's no tag named "boostrap" on Stackoverflow) what is going on? Is everybody developing a case of dyslexia? Am I missing something? Is it a joke? Or am I just going insane?

Comment: 37 pages in total. Quite awesome, yeah. They should make a tag out of it.

Comment: Sorry, why is this such a problem if the tags are correct? When people type quickly they make mitsakes, you know?

Comment: "Is everybody developing a case of dyslexia? Am I missing something? Is it a joke? Or am I just going insane?" All of the above. ;)

Comment: Typos happen, correct them if you want

Comment: @RichardTingle Thank you for the suggestion. May I pass? Google returns 42,000 hits on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Yeah, please do not mass edit 42K questions to fix a typo. :)

Comment: It's the cockney version of Bootstrap. You better leave that tag alone  or you'll have enraged Londoners looking for where you live.

Comment: @Pekka You mean the new tag needs a glottal stop? I didn't know tag names could take those...

Comment: What is this discussion about? I seem to try searching [tag:boostrap] (which results to 0). Either all questions were retagged in 18 minutes, or I am searching on the wrong site?

Comment: @MrLister one of the more grave shortcomings of the tagging system.

Comment: @hjpotter92 It isn't a tag, just a general misspelling in posts.

Comment: @hjpotter92 search for boostrap not as a tag -- http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22boostrap%22

Comment: @hjpotter92 There is not tag named `[boostrap]`. Yet. But just search for `boostrap`, without the tagging delimiters. Or `boostrap site:stackoverflow.com` on Google.

Comment: @bluefeet Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22boostrap%22+-%22bootstrap%22+-%5B*bootstrap*%5D) instead?

Comment: Well, Halloween *is* coming up.  Then again, these entries don't look new.  Spooky.

Comment: It's just people being lazy when talking about `boost::rap`...

Comment: I swear upon all that is holy and good, if someone creates `[boostrap]` I will begin singing the song that ends the world.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that there is something called "boost".

Comment: Did someone mention [tag:boost]